# IllegalStateException in getSectionForPosition use in an indexed list adapter on Nexus S

Tags: android

This is the constructor of my indexed custom SimpleCursorAdapter :

```
public myAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
        String[] from, int[] to, Activity activity) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to);

    this.context = context;
    this.currentCursor = c;
    this.activity = activity;

    indexer = new AlphabetIndexer(c, c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("CARD_title"), "-ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
    sectionToPosition = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>();
    sectionToOffset = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    final int count = super.getCount();

    int i;
    for (i = count - 1 ; i >= 0; i--){
        try {
            int tmp = indexer.getSectionForPosition(i);
            sectionToPosition.put(tmp, i);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.e("LIST_ADAPTER", "error = " + e);
        } catch (CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            Log.e("LIST_ADAPTER", "error = " + e);
        }
    }

    i = 0;
    usedSectionNumbers = new int[sectionToPosition.keySet().size()];

    for (Integer section : sectionToPosition.keySet()){
        sectionToOffset.put(section, i);
        usedSectionNumbers[i] = section;
        i++;
    }

    for(Integer section: sectionToPosition.keySet()){
        sectionToPosition.put(section, sectionToPosition.get(section) + sectionToOffset.get(section));
    }


}
```

The issue is that I always get an IllegalStateException in line :
int tmp = indexer.getSectionForPosition(i);
It only appears in my nexus S android 2.3.6 and the same instruction works great in any other devices.
This is the complete log I got:

```
03-12 19:43:37.496: E/CursorWindow(3021): need to grow: mSize = 1048576, size = 4203, freeSpace() = 2620, numRows = 251
03-12 19:43:37.496: E/CursorWindow(3021): not growing since there are already 251 row(s), max size 1048576
03-12 19:43:37.500: E/Cursor(3021): Failed allocating 4203 bytes for blob at 250,7
03-12 19:43:37.542: E/Cursor(3021): Invalid statement in fillWindow()
03-12 19:43:37.542: E/CursorWindow(3021): Bad request for field slot 0,0. numRows = 0, numColumns = 0
03-12 19:43:37.546: E/AndroidRuntime(3021): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-12 19:43:37.546: E/AndroidRuntime(3021): java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 0 col 0 failed
03-12 19:43:37.546: E/AndroidRuntime(3021):     at android.database.CursorWindow.getLong_native(Native Method)
03-12 19:43:37.546: E/AndroidRuntime(3021):     at android.database.CursorWindow.getLong(CursorWindow.java:380)
03-12 19:43:37.546: E/AndroidRuntime(3021):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getLong(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:108)
03-12 19:43:37.546: E/AndroidRuntime(3021):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:194)
03-12 19:43:37.546: E/AndroidRuntime(3021):     at android.widget.AlphabetIndexer.getSectionForPosition(AlphabetIndexer.java:257)
03-12 19:43:37.546: E/AndroidRuntime(3021):     at com.myApp.novactive.adapter.CardsByNameAdapter.<init>(CardsByNameAdapter.java:88)
03-12 19:43:37.546: E/AndroidRuntime(3021):     at com.myApp.novactive.ListCards$ExtractData$2.run(ListCards.java:392)
03-12 19:43:37.546: E/AndroidRuntime(3021):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-12 19:43:37.546: E/AndroidRuntime(3021):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-12 19:43:37.546: E/AndroidRuntime(3021):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-12 19:43:37.546: E/AndroidRuntime(3021):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-12 19:43:37.546: E/AndroidRuntime(3021):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-12 19:43:37.546: E/AndroidRuntime(3021):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-12 19:43:37.546: E/AndroidRuntime(3021):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-12 19:43:37.546: E/AndroidRuntime(3021):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-12 19:43:37.546: E/AndroidRuntime(3021):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-12 19:43:40.066: E/CursorWindow(3021): need to grow: mSize = 1048576, size = 4203, freeSpace() = 938, numRows = 252
03-12 19:43:40.066: E/CursorWindow(3021): not growing since there are already 252 row(s), max size 1048576
03-12 19:43:40.066: E/Cursor(3021): Failed allocating 4203 bytes for blob at 251,7
```

An idea? Thanks!

Comment: is there anything at all in your cursor?

Comment: My cursor returns 342 objects and I included all rows in my query.

Comment: if I may suggest, you probably should fetch the section on a per-need basis

Comment: I don't really understand to fetch on a per-need basis...

Comment: i mean retrieve the matching section only when you need to know for a particular item, because here you force going through the complete cursor

Comment: Ok. It's clear but I need match section for all items. It's the pbm :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Bad request for field slot 0,0. numRows = 0, numColumns = 0 03-12 18:34:29.667: E/LIST_ADAPTER(2623): error = java.lang.IllegalStateException
```

Exception clearly indicating that no data in cursor, make sure you are getting some data.

Another suggestion is, make sure you are pointed to first element of cursor by calling `c.moveToFirst()`, before doing any operations on cursor.

Comment: My cursor returns 342 rows and I correctly put cursor.moveToFirst after my query. The same code works on all devices except nexus S ...

Comment: How did you make sure you got 342 rows? Could you do same validations right before indexer=....?

Comment: this is c state right before indexer = ...    mCount 342 . I got it after a breakpoint right before indexer line

Comment: Can you update original post with more stack trace? lines before and after this error?